# Return the number of array elements in order that satisfy a condition

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to make my function return the number of the maximum number of array indexes where, when added together in order, equal 0 - not easy to explain, but below are some annotated test examples:

```
longestSlice([-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1]); // should return 7 (slice starts at 2nd position)
longestSlice([1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1]); // should return 4 (both the first four elements and the last four elements)
longestSlice([-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1]); // should return 5 (slice starts at 4th position)
```

My function returns the first 2 tests correctly, but not the 3rd test. I think my logic is wrong, but I can't for the life of me figure out the logic to solve it. How can this be achieved? I've tried:

```
// if a[i] + a[i+1] = 0, count++, then if a[i-1] + a[i+2] = 0, count++ etc - won't work
// if a[i] + a[i+1] + a[i+2] + ... + a[i+n/2] > n (or -n) - won't work
// tests considering: count no of -1, 0 and 1 instances
```

Also, could somebody explain how to easily achieve a solution to situations like this, as it seems more difficult than it looks, and I'm relatively new to javascript. Thanks for any advice here.

```js
function longestSlice(arr) {

 var N = arr.length;
 var totalSum = 0, sliceLength = 0;
 var slices = [];

 if (N < 1) {
  throw new RangeError('Bad Input - Function Aborted');
 } else {
  // continue...
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
   totalSum += arr[i];
   sliceLength++;
   console.log('totalSum: ' + totalSum + '\nsliceLength: ' + sliceLength);
   
   if (totalSum === 0) {
    slices.push(sliceLength);
    sliceLength = 0;
    console.log('sliceLength reset to: ' + sliceLength);
   }
  }
  return slices;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Let's take it in this way:

Assume we have a array length `N`, sum of the array is `X`. Now...

if `X` is zero then its `N` (length of the array) is the max numbers which will sum up to `0`.

If `X` is not zero then there could be some numbers (assume K number of numbers) which will sum up to value `X` and the resultant length should be `N-K` the max number of numbers which will sum up to zero. In case there is no `K (1<=K<=N)` number of numbers forms `0 (by sum)` then the array cannot produce a zero by sum of any combinations.

Well, if it's little confusing, let's take an example.

Assume a array of length `75` (so, `N` is `75` here)

Now, assume maximum sum of `73` numbers (of a specific combination) is equal to `0` (so here `K` is `73`) and total array sum is `15` so definitely its the sum of rest `2` numbers (in that combination where other `73` numbers sums up to `0`)

So, instead of searching the longest combination of sum value `0`, we can search the smallest combination of sum value `15` (which is the entire array sum, here denoted by `X` in previous statement) we can simply subtract with `length` of inputs and gotthe result. In this was, we can

1. Avoid recursion
2. Avoid generating combinations upto length resultant (eg upto length `73`,
   exit after finding all combination of length `2` and their sums)
3. Re use results from last combinations to generate next length
   combinations
4. Exit when we found sum is `X` (sum of the entire array) will
   smallest possible combination

So, The final steps of the algo:

1. First step: `sum` up the array
2. check if `sum` is `0` return the length of `array`
3. If `sum` is not zero then start from combination of length `1`. for
   length `1` we can avoid calculating `sum` since length `1` so the
   item itself will be the `sum` value for that combination (of 1). so
   if item found having value `X (the entire sum)` we ban break and
   return `<Inputs length - 1>`
   If, `X` not found then start process for generating all the combinations of 2 numbers and calculate sum. If we found that the sum is `X` then we can break and return `N - 2`. If all combos processed with length `2` and still `X` din not found we can pass all the combinations of length `2` and generate all the combinations of length `3`, and then `4` and so on. whenever we will get the result (having sum value equal to `X`) we will break and return (`N - 3`) or (`N - 4`) accordingly.

Now, move forward to create combinations with length `2, 3, 4...`

We, can create combinations of values, but since values can be duplicated that will be difficult to manage, so we will create combinations of `indexes`, and we can have a lookup for values in out input array any time to generate sum.

Assume a array having `4` elements, so we can have combinations of `1, 2, 3 and 4`

Lets generate the indexes and re use for next time:

```js
let array = [-15, 10, 5, 13],
  cm;

function comboNext(a, L) {
  let res = [], i;
  a.forEach(p => {
    let last = p[p.length - 1], i;
    for (i = last + 1; i < L; i++) {res.push(p.concat(i)); }
  })
  return res;
}

//this is not part of algo, just to format properly
//to display the combinations properly
function format(c) {
  return c.map(n=>n.join('+')).join(',\n')
  }

cm = array.map((v, i) => [i]); //just indexes for 1 length combos
console.log(format(cm) + ' => All of length 1');


cm = comboNext(cm, array.length);
console.log(format(cm) +  ' => All of length 2');


cm = comboNext(cm, array.length);
console.log(format(cm) +  ' => All of length 3');

cm = comboNext(cm, array.length);
console.log(format(cm) +  ' => All of length 4');
```

Since, we are re using previous combinations, using last index of each and then starting from that position it will

Avoid duplicate combinations and will pick all the unique one
It will always push incremental index, so we can pick the last one (it will be the bigger one) and process straight forward instead of searching a element in the combo and avoid that combo if the element exists. This situation will never come. for example, you have the combination of index `0 1, 2` and you are processing `2` you will no need to process. you can start processing from `3` straight away. similarly if you have a combo of indexes `1,2, 5` you have to process from `6` for that, don't bother about `3,4` in other combinations they will come like `2,3,4` so when processing `5` it will generate `2,3,4,5` and `2,3,4,6` accordingly. so you will not miss anything.

Now, lets have an implementation. instead of returning raw combo arrays, we will return a object having `success` flag and the combo last time processed. and we will use simple `for loop` to able to do `exit/break/return` at any point of time.

```js
function longestSlice(arr) {
  let len = arr.length,
    sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b),
    sumAtIndexes = idxs => idxs.reduce((s, e) => s + arr[e], 0),
    comboFor1 = a => {
      let i, combo = [];
      for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (a[i] === sum) {
          return {
            success: true,
            length: len - 1
          }
        } else {
          combo.push([i])
        }
      }
      return {
        success: false,
        combo,
        length: 0
      };
    },
    comboForN = prevCombos => {
      let combo = [],
        i, com;
      for (i = 0; i < prevCombos.length; i++) {
        let p = prevCombos[i],
          last = p[p.length - 1],
          j;
        for (j = last + 1; j < len; j++) {
          com = p.concat(j);
          if (sumAtIndexes(com) === sum) {
            return {
              success: true,
              length: len - com.length
            }
          }
          combo.push(p.concat(j))
        }
      }
      return {
        success: false,
        combo,
        length: 0
      }
    },
    counter = 1,
    combosWithFlag;

  if (sum === 0) {
    return len;
  }

  combosWithFlag = comboFor1(arr);

  for (counter = 2; !combosWithFlag.success && counter <= len; counter++) {
    combosWithFlag = comboForN(combosWithFlag.combo);
  }
  return combosWithFlag.length;
}

console.log(longestSlice([-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1]))
console.log(longestSlice([1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1]));
console.log(longestSlice([-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1]));
console.log(longestSlice([10,20,30,40,-100,-50,25,30, 15,17,3]))
```

Note that I have used 2 different function, 1 for creating combinations of length 1 (as that if far simple, and we can avoid sum there) and another one for creating combination of any length and having input the last length combinations of indexes.

Answer (score 1):

You will basically need a double loop..

The outer loop will start at the first array element,.

The sub loop then loops from this start to the end, and keeps a sum, whenever that sum equals 0, it checks to see if it's the largest and stores if it is.

Example below..

```js
function longestSlice (a) {
  let longest = 0;
  for (let s = 0; s < a.length; s ++) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let sl = s; sl < a.length; sl ++) {
      sum += a[sl];
      if (sum === 0) {
        const t = sl - s + 1;
        if (t > longest) longest = t;
      }
    }
  }
  return longest;
}


const ret = [
  longestSlice([-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1]),
  longestSlice([1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1]),
  longestSlice([-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1])
];

console.log(ret);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have implemented similar algorithm before. It can be done recursively

```
function longestSlice(arr, acc=0) {

    let N = arr.length;

    if (N == 0) {
        return acc
    } else {
        let sum = 0
        let bestSoFar = 0;
        for (let i =0; i < N; i++) {
            sum += arr[i]
            if (sum ==0) {
                bestSoFar = i+1;
            }
        }

        return  longestSlice(arr.slice(1,N), Math.max(bestSoFar, acc));
    }
}


longestSlice([-1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, -1, -1]);    // returns 5
```

Comment: I really like your solution, but i don't understand one thing - how does this actually work? Because in this case, sum is never 0! (except before the for loop)

Comment: @user8758206 yes, `sum` should continue adding up until reaches the end of the input array. In this process, everytime sum becomes zero, it records the current length (best slice so far) to `bestSoFar`. This way, it won't stop exploring before reaching the longest slice.

Answer (score 1):

```
function longestSlice(arr) {
  let longestSliceLength = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - longestSliceLength; i++) {
    let sum = 0
    let currentSliceLength = 0
    for (let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
      currentSliceLength++;
      sum += arr[j]
      if (!sum && longestSliceLength < currentSliceLength) {
        longestSliceLength = currentSliceLength
      }
    }
  }
  return longestSliceLength
}
```

> could somebody explain how to easily achieve a solution to situations like this

Well, we need an algorithm to solve this problem, and don't really have any time/space restrictions. How can we go about this problem? The longest sub-sequence should be smaller than the sequence itself (obvious, part of finite object is less than or equal to the object size). Let's try all the consecutive sub-sequences then, starting with the largest one (starting from the very first element that is, but we could start from the other end if we want to). Add number, calculate the sum and the number of elements already in the sum. When the sum is equal to zero - we have a sub-sequence which satisfies the requirements. We save it's length if it is the largest length we saw so far. Repeat. Hope this helps.